# UIAccelerometer help?

Tags: ios, accelerometer

After a google or two, I came up with this code to save the current position the user is in (so I can calibrate it) and save it to NSUserDefaults. This is in my settings view:

```
//Add code for calibrating accelerometer
        UIAcceleration *acceleration;
        float accelX = (acceleration.x - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"X-Calibrate"]);
        float accelY = (acceleration.y - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"Y-Calibrate"]);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelX forKey:@"X-Calibrate"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelY forKey:@"Y-Calibrate"];
```

To reset the calibration I do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0 forKey:@"X-Calibrate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0 forKey:@"Y-Calibrate"];
```

Now here is where I need a slight bit of help. Now that I have these values in NSUserDefaults. How would I apply it to the following code so that the calibration is 'fully' implemented?
Here is the code for the accelerometer currently:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceration {
    AccelPoint.x += (acceration.x*50);
    if (AccelPoint.x < 0) {
        AccelPoint.x = 320;
    }
    if (AccelPoint.x > 320) {
        AccelPoint.x = 0;
    }
    playerSpeed += 0.066;
    AccelPoint.y += playerSpeed;
    Square.center = AccelPoint; 
}
```

This is some of the variables and how they are defined:

```
CGPoint AccelPoint;
float playerSpeed;
```

Thanks!

Also quick little site question for that accelerometer code, should I be using if-elseif? Would that be more efficient or should I leave it at if-if?

**Edit1:**

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceration {
    float accelX = (acceration.x - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"X-Calibrate"]);
    float accelY = (acceration.y - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"Y-Calibrate"]);
    AccelPoint.x += (accelX*50);
    if (AccelPoint.x < 0) {
        AccelPoint.x = 320;
    }
    if (AccelPoint.x > 320) {
        AccelPoint.x = 0;
    }
    playerSpeed += 0.066;

    AccelPoint.y += playerSpeed;

    Square.center = AccelPoint;

}
```

**In my code, I am not using accelY. How should I apply that to my code? I cleaned up the code a bit to make it a bit clearer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you want use the data you're storing, but to access it it's just:

```
float xCal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"X-Calibrate"];
float yCal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"Y-Calibrate"];
```

EDIT:

So based on your comment, maybe try something like this.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *) acceration {
    float accelX = (acceration.x - xCal);
    float accelY = (acceration.y - yCal);
    AccelPoint.x += (accelX*50);
    if (AccelPoint.x < 0) {
        AccelPoint.x = 320;
    }
    if (AccelPoint.x > 320) {
        AccelPoint.x = 0;
    }
    playerSpeed += 0.066;
    AccelPoint.y += playerSpeed;
    Square.center = AccelPoint; 
}
```

Comment: I want to read those values and apply them to the UIAccelerometer so that say the user is playing on their side, the game's accelerometer will work as if the user was holding it normally.

Comment: In that code, you are not using accelY. How should I apply that to my code? Also check my Edit1 in my original post, I cleaned up the code a bit to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Still need help with the accelY issue!

Comment: I think I actually don't need the Y coordinate since my app is only in portrait so I am just going to leave it at X and I think it should be fine!